# Unit root test with different trend types

Tags: trend, unit-root, stationarity

Basic unit root tests include only constant and linear trend case. So, what should I do if I want to test hypothesis about quadratic trend stationarity asumption, for example? What test should I use? Or what strategy does exist to determine stationarity  in relation to high degree polynominal?

Thank you.